# Delete object in bucket, C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I'm trying to delete an object from a bucket. Reading the docs it all sounds super simple, but I just can't seem to get it working. On the server side I have the following in ASP.NET:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("api/forge/oss/objects/delete")]
public async Task<dynamic> DeleteObject_fromBucket()
{
    // basic input validation
    HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(req.Params["bucketKey"]))
        throw new System.Exception("BucketKey parameter was not provided.");

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(req.Params["objectName"]))
        throw new System.Exception("ObjectName parameter was not provided."); 

    string bucketKey = req.Params["bucketKey"];
    string objectName = req.Params["objectName"];

    // call API to delete object on the bucket
    dynamic oauth = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();
    ObjectsApi objects = new ObjectsApi();
    string access_token = oauth.access_token; ;
    objects.Configuration.AccessToken = access_token;

    // delete the file/object
    await objects.DeleteObjectAsync(bucketKey, objectName);
    return 0;
}
```

The client side:

```
function deleteObject(node) {
    result = window.confirm('Wollen Sie dieses Modell löschen');
    if (result == false) { return; }
    else {
        var bucketKey = node.parents[0];
        var objectName = node.text;

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('bucketKey', bucketKey);
        formData.append('objectName', objectName);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/forge/oss/objects/delete',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,  
            processData: false,
            type: 'DELETE',  // man könnte auch method: schreiben
            success: function (data) {
                $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).refresh_node(node);
            }
        });
    }       
}
```

I always get the exception that it fails to make API call. The bucketKey and objectName are both Strings. Could anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: During the function:    await objects.DeleteObjectAsync(bucketKey, objectName);

Comment: And what is the exception exactly?

Comment: Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException:
        //     Thrown when fails to make API call

Comment: I think the oauth object you are using is not valid. Also the objects is empty when you try to delete from it.

Comment: You were rigth. I had to add another scope to the token. Then it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I happened to make a working code for one attendee in Sydney Accelerator this week. The code snippet is tested on [Learn Forge Tutorial (2 legged workflow)](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/net). One is deleting bucket, the other is deleting object. It looks you are also testing with that skeleton of tutorial?

I made a similar code like yours at the beginning, but my VS threw error when compiling. Finally, I found it is due to the return value. Since it is a HTTP Request, it looks 0 does not make sense to a response. In addition, the default scope of the internal token in that tutorial does not contain bucket delete and data write (for deleting object). I got the detail error with the response of client side.

After adding those scopes at OAuthController.cs. All started to work:

```
 public static async Task<dynamic> GetInternalAsync()
 {
  if (InternalToken == null || InternalToken.ExpiresAt < 
   DateTime.UtcNow)
  {
    InternalToken = await Get2LeggedTokenAsync(new Scope[] { 
       Scope.BucketCreate, Scope.BucketRead, Scope.DataRead, 
       Scope.DataCreate,Scope.BucketDelete,Scope.DataWrite});
        InternalToken.ExpiresAt = 
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(InternalToken.expires_in);
  }

  return InternalToken;
}
```

If these are not helpful for your case, I'd suggest building the [Forge SDK source project](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client), adding to your project, and debugging the corresponding methods to see what the exact error is. Please feel free to let us know if you have any questions on this.

**Server Side:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/forge/oss/buckets/delete")]
    public async Task<dynamic> DeleteBucket([FromBody]CreateBucketModel bucket)
    {
        BucketsApi buckets = new BucketsApi();
        dynamic token = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();
        buckets.Configuration.AccessToken = token.access_token; 

        await buckets.DeleteBucketAsync(bucket.bucketKey); 
        //or
        //buckets.DeleteBucket(bucket.bucketKey); 

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/forge/oss/objects/delete")]
    public async Task<dynamic> DeleteObject([FromBody]DeleteObjectModel 
                                                      objInfo)
    {
        ObjectsApi objs = new ObjectsApi();
        dynamic token = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();
        objs.Configuration.AccessToken = token.access_token;

        await objs.DeleteObjectAsync(objInfo.bucketKey, objInfo.objectKey);

        //or
        //objs.DeleteObject(objInfo.bucketKey, objInfo.objectKey); 

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class CreateBucketModel
    {
      public string bucketKey { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeleteObjectModel
    {
       public string bucketKey { get; set; }
       public string objectKey { get; set; } 
     }
```

**Client Side:**

```
function deleteBucket() {
     //select one bucket node of the tree
     var bucketKey = $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).get_selected(true)[0].id;

     var policyKey = $('#newBucketPolicyKey').val();
     jQuery.post({
        url: '/api/forge/oss/buckets/delete',
             contentType: 'application/json',
             data: JSON.stringify({ 'bucketKey': bucketKey, 
                                    'policyKey': policyKey }),
             success: function (res) {
               $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).refresh();
               alert('Bucket  deleted') 
              },
             error: function (err) {
               alert('Bucket not deleted')
               console.log(err);
             }
         });
     }

   function deleteObject() {
      //assume the first selected tree node is bucket
      var bucketKey = $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).get_selected(true)[0].text;
      //assume the second selected tree node is object
      var objectKey = $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).get_selected(true)[1].text;
      jQuery.post({
          url: '/api/forge/oss/objects/delete',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify({ 'bucketKey': bucketKey, 
                                 'objectKey': objectKey }),
          success: function (res) {
             $('#appBuckets').jstree(true).refresh();
             alert('Object  deleted') 
          },
          error: function (err) {
            alert('Object not deleted')
            console.log(err);
          }
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

URL should be
  url: '/api/forge/oss/objects/delete' 
instead of   url: 'api/forge/oss/objects/delete'

Comment: Not necessarily. If the application is not at the domain root your suggestion would fail. If it is there, it would not make any difference.